# how do I solve this limit question?

Tags: limits

How do I find $\lim_{x  \to 5} \frac{x^2-4x-5}{x-5}$?

I've tried putting $x=5$ into this formula but I get an error.

What do I do? Does anyone know?

Comment: Have you tried factorising the numerator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $\frac{x^2-4x-5}{x-5} \equiv \require{cancel} \frac{\cancel{(x-5)}(x+1)}{\cancel{(x-5)}} \equiv x+1.$

Now take the limit as $x \to 5$ and all is well.

---

Note that we can cancel $(x-5)$ terms as $x \neq 5$.